# How to retrieve the supported android JNI version in a device?

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I need to know if JNI is supported in a android device and which version. Which function call can I use for doing this ? Also should I call this from Java side or the NDK side ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use JNI from any Android app on any device.

JNI provides a `GetVersion` call.  You can also specify a minimum version as the return value from `JNI_OnLoad` or as an argument to `AttachCurrentThread`.

Older versions of Android supported 1.4.  Newer versions support 1.6.

As always, it's good to start with the [JNI Tips](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html) page.

Comment: Any **Android** device.  Apparently the application translation/repackaging thing Blackberry was doing for a while to import Android apps did not support JNI.  Also, as Android runs on a variety of ABIs, JNI will only be usable where a library compatible with the device's ABI is provided.

Comment: Retrieving the JNI version isn't going to help much with that.  At some point, the way you tell if something works is by trying the thing and seeing if it works. :-)  Hopefully the app would not be installed at all on a device for which it lacks the necessary .so binaries or where .so doesn't work at all, but I suppose that does rely on the app being installed through a decent app store.

Comment: Hi fadden, you answer that JNI version support can vary helped me solve the issue. I can also use GetEnv function which will return JNI_OK if the version is supported from JNI_OnLoad. Ofcourse, the real question now falls if such a support can be detected from the manifest itself !! Because it will show that the app is not supported for so and so phone (for example from the google play store).